# Asynchronous problems writing to server

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, windows-8, windows-8.1

The application is for the Windows 8 Mobile platform, and it tends to crash when I send some data to the server at a point during it's life cycle.

```
            await writer.StoreAsync();
```

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072745)

Even if I put it in a try catch, I can't throw the exception, since it feels it still closes the program.

When a button is pressed, it sends a message to the server;

```
       private  void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Task t = new Task(TalkToServer);

        if (t.IsCompleted != t.IsCompleted)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            t.RunSynchronously();


        }
    }
```

So if I press the button it will start a new task. If the task is completed, then run the task, else if it isn't then do not.

```
    private async void TalkToServer()
    {
        if (clientSocket == null)
            return;
        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(clientSocket.OutputStream);

        MessageData md = new MessageData();
        md.MyUser = new User("us", "ps");
        md.MyType = MessageData.mType.REQUESTMEMBERS;
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(md);
        writer.WriteString(output);
        await writer.StoreAsync();


        await writer.FlushAsync();
        writer.DetachStream();
    }
```

This is the method call that sends the data, but `await writer.StoreAsync();`
 tends to crash the program. This code is used in the beggining of a program on a seperate page and it works, but it dues to

EDIT ---- after looking at the further reading that user method man had presented, I changed the implementation to :

```
        private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await sendInfo();
    }

    private async Task sendInfo()
    {

        if (clientSocket == null)
            return;
        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(clientSocket.OutputStream);

        MessageData md = new MessageData();
        md.MyUser = new User("us", "ps");
        md.MyType = MessageData.mType.REQUESTMEMBERS;
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(md);
        writer.WriteString(output);
        await writer.StoreAsync();


        await writer.FlushAsync();
        writer.DetachStream();
        return ;
    }
```

Also the title was changed

Comment: look at this previously posted answer for some helpful hints / clues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359004/streamsocket-datawriter-storeasync-datareader-loadasync-asynchronous-pr

Comment: @MethodMan It appears he has the same problem I do, my message framing is fine, but it's the Aysnc calls that are clashing I presume? I made an edit to the question, but that still hasn't fixed it.

Comment: @Moynul if you put try-catch in the `sendInfo()` what error do you see?

Comment: Did you try to use it without the Async? Does it have a synchronic writer.Store() method? If it does maybe it will be easier to spot the problem.

Comment: @Ian if I put a try catch block, the application doesn't close, however the problem is that it disconnects from the server.

Comment: @DennisNerush I have checked the documentation and there is no Sync method. Only Async